# What is the product of following iodoform reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organic-oxidation

**Question**

1. [image: List item]

**Attempt**
I think the product A would be as I have attempted below, but I am getting the answer as A but book says D. 
[image]
Where am I wrong? Please help.

Comment: if there was excess I2 present would it add across the double bond of the iodoform product that you have drawn?

Comment: But still even if I2 adds I+ and OH- across double bond, how would we get d?

Comment: The intermediate hydroxy acid gets oxidised to keto acid by I2 perhaps?

Comment: Alpha keto acids readily decarboxylate https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/acs.orglett.6b01964

Comment: Can you give a mechanism? Because although i understand how C-OH will convert to C=O and help in decarboxylation, I dont understand what will happen to I that attacked C=C in first place?

Comment: Form the hydroxy iodide by addition to the double bond then OH opening the iodonium giving the tertiary iodide/alpha hydroxy acid. I2 oxidises the hydroxy to the keto acid which decarboxylates. OH- eliminates I- to form double bond.